# Capitalize first letter of last name in column of a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I would like to capitalize first letter for the last name and erase extra spaces as well as remove comma or period in my table by running a query by sql view.

Comment: Yes, List1 = ListBox and Command1 = Command Button, after I changed to just a click and click the button it gives me an error, says "Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null" and then highlight the second line "List1 = Replace(List1, ",", ""), how can I solve the error? thanks alot

Comment: so do you mean erase "Private Sub Command1_Click()" and paste the "If IsNull(List1) or List1 = "" "?

Comment: keeps giving me an error if I use only "If IsNull(List1) or List1 = "" " it says that "Expected : Then or toGo"

Comment: Im sorry but after I put the above code, and click the button, there is no change to my list as well as no error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make changes to a table containing names, run the query shown below (change the table name and field names to match your database).

This will:

- Remove leading and trailing spaces
- Change the first character of the name to Uppercase
- This will NOT change the case of any other letters in the string

  ```
  UPDATE TblEmployee SET TblEmployee.FirstName = UCase(Mid(Trim([FirstName]),1,1)) & 
  Mid(Trim([FirstName]),2), TblEmployee.LastName = UCase(Mid(Trim([LastName]),1,1)) & 
  Mid(Trim([LastName]),2);
  ```

Comment: Yes you were right, it says "List1 is Null or Empty", how can I solve this problem,, thanks again

Comment: List1 is not empty when I see that on form view, there are some dummy variables I put like "aaa, fawefewa., wefewfwe. ~ " in the listbox

Comment: (1) first what I want to do is, I would like to change the last name column from the import data, because some of the first letters are not capitalized or some of the names have extra spaces or commas, therefore I want to fix those bad data. (2) Row Source says "SELECT [Table1].[ID], [Table1].[Field1] FROM Table1 ORDER BY [Field1];" and Row Source Type says "Table/Query" (3) I cannot select multiple items from the Form View. (4) I want the fixed data to be updated in a table form, but it really doesn't matter unless the data has been fixed

Comment: yes you are right (Jr or Sr) too, and there is also a separate column that holds the first name, and I have to capitalize the first letter of First name too. If I can do those all by running a query, it is absolutely fine thank you so much

Comment: I provided a solution. But now based on your clarification, many people that see this post will scratch their head because the answer looks totally unrelated to your original question. Please update your question, then delete all comments you have made so far so this will get cleaned up.

Comment: Thank you I will fix those after it runs, buy Im really new to access but should I use update query for using the code you provided? and does TblEmployee refer to the table name? if my table name is table1, do I have to use table1 instead of TblEmployee?

Comment: do you know how to erase comma or period before/after the names??? can I still use like TblEmployee.LastName = Replace(TblEmployee.LastName, ",", "")  like this?

Comment: it gives me the error, says "duplicate output destination" when I use the code "TblEmployee.LastName = Replace(TblEmployee.LastName, ",", "")

Comment: there are some mistakes when the client company gives us a data and those mistakes are, they put comma or period at the end of the last name such as doe, or doe. .Therefore I just want to remove the comma or period just after the last name

Comment: I created a Function that will clean up all the names in a table as you requested, but will not post unless this question get's defined properly (state the real issue and what needs to happen). Also, all of these meaningless comments we both have made should be deleted.